# Display an array of images in collectionCell inside collectionCell for scrolling. use Class

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, collections, firebase-realtime-database

I use **viewController** and **collectionView** inside **collectionView**. **1st collectionView** need to do make a table, **2nd collectionView** need to **scrolling images**.

I can display one **image**, but in my **class Model** should load more images (**image, image2, image3**).

So my **class Model:**

```
class Model {

    var image: String
    var image2: String
    var image3: String
    var images: [String] = []
    var images2: [String] = []
    var images3: [String] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let snap = value["hall1"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap2 = value["hall2"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap3 = value["hall3"] as? NSDictionary
        image = snap?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image2 = snap2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image3 = snap3?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

My **viewController**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var image: [Model] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Студии2")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImage: [Model] = []

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {
                let imageObj = Model(snapshot: imageSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newImage.append(imageObj)
            }
            self.image = newImage
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return image.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell11
        cell.vc1 = self
        cell.imagess = [image[indexPath.item]]
        return cell
    }
}
```

My **collectionCell1**:

```
class CollectionViewCell11: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var imagess: [Model] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var vc1: ViewController?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagess.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell12
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item].image))
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if vc1 != nil {
            let vc2 = vc1!.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
            vc2.photo = [imagess[indexPath.item]]
            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            backItem.title = ""
            vc1!.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
            vc1!.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And my **collectionCell2**:

```
class CollectionViewCell12: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Use string in **collectionCell1** impossible, because class **Model** have an array **images** for future pass in next **viewController**.

I'm novice, but i think need use another class **Model** inside **new** class. But I could be wrong.
I understand my mistake, my mistake is in **collectionCell1** line -

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item].image))
```

But i don't understand what I can do...

it should look like this:

[image]

But earlier i use type **String** in **var imagess** and now me need use **class Model**

[GitHub Link](http://github.com/denikaev/promotest)

Comment: Have you successfully created *one* horizontal-scrolling collection view with multiple images?

Comment: @DonMag  you mean the included .gif? If you mean .gif - yes, but i used in line **cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item].image))** this line **cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagess[indexPath.item]))** because **imagess** was a **string**, but me need to use **class Model**.

Comment: Not sure where your problem is... In your .gif, you have a vertical-scroll CollectionView with a horizontal-scroll collection view in each cell, and you are loading the correct images in each cell of the h-scroll collection? What is not working?

Comment: @DonMag  It works if I use **var imagess: [String] = []** in **collectionCell1**, but if i use **String** i will not be able to pass an array on next **viewController** so now me need use **var imagess: [Model] = []**. But when i use **var imagess [Model] = []** i can display only one image in **viewController**. In .gif it's example should it look like.

Comment: Hmmm... so, you have the *display* working? You just are having trouble accessing the correct information when a cell is tapped?

Comment: @DonMag  Not tapped. Display working and have one image, but when loading app should see multiple images in vertical cells for horizontal scroll. I hope, I did not confused you?
May be need put an array in **sd_setImage...** or need to put **string image** with **didSet** in **collectionCell2**, but don't understand how to do it... :(

Comment: Sorry - still confused... In you .gif, you show 2 "rows" each with 2 cells. Do you mean you want each cell in each row to also be a vertical-scrolling collection view? So you scroll up-and-down by touching only *between the rows*? But if you touch-drag up-and-down on an image it will scroll another set of images?

Comment: @DonMag Yes. I can give you my source code, maybe you will be easier to understand what is it and how it works.

Comment: If you can put an example somewhere (such as GitHub), I'll be happy to take a look. Keep in mind, though, if it requires more than just open-and-run, it may not help (i.e. if it requires a bunch of 3rd-party libs or registrations or whatnot).

Comment: @DonMag  pls check 
https://github.com/denikaev/promotest

Code is very simple, just open and run

I hope you can help me, otherwise my brain soon will crash :(

Comment: OK - first, it looks like you are trying to assign too much Control to your cells. I'm going to fork your github repo and make a couple changes (too much to write in a comment here).

Comment: What is supposed to happen when an individual image is tapped? Should it push to a new view controller which display *only* the tapped image? Or the new VC should display a collection view of the same images from that row? Or something else?

Comment: @DonMag Big thanks for your help. New VC should display array of images from class Model - var images: [String] = [], if you tap an individual image

Comment: Do you want to pass the Model that was used for the whole row? Or do you want to know which individual image was tapped?

Comment: @DonMag i want to pass Model for individual image on new VC

Comment: And need to display array images of class Model (var image: String, var image2: string) in each row in each cells, because in GitHub project in row i can display only one image in each row

Comment: @DonMag like a AppStore, if you click on game, you pass on nextVC and nextVC displays screenshots of application

Comment: OK - try not to think too far ahead... You start with (currently) 2 "rows", and each row has two pictures (cells). When you tap on a picture... do you want to show a new view with information about **all pictures in that row**? Or do you want to show a new view with information about **that picture**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154911/discussion-between-donmag-and-onpro).

Comment: @DonMag In my firebase struct each image have a array images, so i want to show new array of images which stored in class Model in var images: [String] = []. I can add in questions my firebase struct.